# How can we find the name of the constraint from the Database.?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table prsl which have auto generated name of the constraint. I want to search where the Database kept these name. 
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PRSL] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK__PRSL__1C1D47DC0BF1ACC7]

Actually, i want to drop these constraints dynamically. 
For Example

```
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PRSL]')
```

drop all the constraint which are on a table.

Drop constraint 'when found'

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to display all constraints of a given table

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR TABLE NAME'
```

If you want to drop all constraints of the given table use this:

```
DECLARE @database nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @table nvarchar(50)

set @database = 'dotnetnuke'
set @table = 'tabs'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(255)
WHILE EXISTS(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where constraint_catalog = @database and table_name = @table)
BEGIN
    select    @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    where    constraint_catalog = @database and 
            table_name = @table
    exec    sp_executesql @sql
END
```

It worked for me...Hope it helps...